# Can't set Databricks account admin using Terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-service-principal, terraform-provider-databricks

I want to set the account admin for a service principal in order to create the Unity Catalog metastore. The Terraform code looks like this:

```
data "databricks_service_principal" "application" {
  count = var.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0

  application_id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}

resource "databricks_service_principal_role" "account_admin" {
  count = var.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0

  service_principal_id = data.databricks_service_principal.application[0].id
  role                 = "account_admin"
}
```

This should theoretically work according to the answers in [this thread](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/creating-a-service-principal-with-admin-role-on-account-level-in/m-p/23631).

But unfortunately I get following error from Terraform for the resource "databricks_service_principal_role": `Error: cannot read service principal role: Service Principal has no role`

For me this error message is not very useful and I don't know what is wrong here. Is this maybe a bug in the Databricks Terraform provider?

Site notes (if relevant):

- I'm using the newest Databricks Terraform provider (V 1.21)
- The Databricks workspace is deployed in Azure.
- Using the "databrick_user_role" resource and trying to assign the account_admin role to a Databricks user will produce the same error message: `User has no role`

Looking at the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/master/aws/resource_service_principal_role.go) (Databricks Terraform provider) I found the error message from above but I don't understand why the `ReadContext` section in there is even executed.

It would be really nice if someone can help me, as I have to enable the Unity Catalog metastore very soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works just fine, like this:

```
data "databricks_service_principal" "application" {
  application_id = "xxxxxxxxxx"
}

resource "databricks_service_principal_role" "account_admin" {
  service_principal_id = data.databricks_service_principal.application.id
  role                 = "account_admin"
}
```

Most probably you have the provider miscofigured - this should happen if you're trying to do this on the workspace level, while it should be done on the account level.

```
provider "databricks" {
  host = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id = "xxxxx"
}
```

P.S. It could be confusing because right now Unity Catalog resources are created via workspace-level API.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how I can get the `account_id` of the service principal the Databricks workspace was created with? When I use the `account_id` from my own user, I get following error message from the "databricks_service_principal_role" resource: `Error: cannot read service principal role: This API is disabled for users without account admin status. Contact your administrator for more information`

Comment: You need to be account admin to do that

Comment: As far as I know there is currently no user or service principal with account admin permission in our Databricks workspace. How can we then set the account admin role to a user/service principal?  Or is the user who created the Databricks workspace automatically account admin by default?

Comment: it's not set on the workspace level - it's set on the account level. and to make SP an account admin it should be executed against account API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that!! Looking at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/#establish-first-account-admin) I assume someone must have the Azure AD Global Administrator role first, then sign in to Databricks account console and manually grant the account admin to the desired user or service principal, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Azure AD Global Administrator is necessary only for first user, then it could add more

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. For me there is still one question opened: I want to configure my Terraform Databricks provider (account level) with the account ID of a service principal because I can't use Azure CLI authentication. I have set the account admin role for the service principal. But how can I get the account ID from that service principal? As it's not a real user, I can't login to the account console with it and therefor can't obtain the account ID. Or is there another way? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Account ID is ID for your Databricks account that is linked to Azure AD tenant. Service principal is identified by Application ID.